# Query division in oracle

Tags: oracle, decimal, division

how can I divide the result of query1 to query2? (The result has decimal points.) Thank you:

query1:

```
select count(*) as aa 
  from registered_devices 
 where status = 1;
```

query2:

```
select sum(last_count) as current_daily 
  from statistics             
 where to_char(counter_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') between to_char (sysdate - 1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24')                      
   and to_char (sysdate - 1 /24, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') 
   and counter_type = 'WS_GET_OFFER_ACCEPT'
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with each other, make simple `where counter_date between sysdate - 1 and sysdate - 1 /24`, resp. `where TRUNC(counter_date, 'MI') between TRUNC(sysdate - 1, 'MI') and TRUNC(sysdate - 1 /24, 'MI')`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
select (select count(*) as aa 
          from registered_devices 
        where status = 1)
       / (select sum(last_count) as current_daily 
            from statistics             
            where to_char(counter_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24')
                   between to_char (sysdate - 1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24')                      
                       and to_char (sysdate - 1 /24, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') 
              and counter_type = 'WS_GET_OFFER_ACCEPT')
  from dual
```

(or vice-versa if you meant the other way).

Beware of divide-by-zero error!